# How to output the number of elements based on a certain criteria?

Tags: javascript

I want to count the number of specific cars and output the cars,
I can count the number of saabs, but when i try to out the 2 saab cars i am getting "sa"

updated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
cars=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Ford","Saab"];
var count=0;
var totalSuccessArray= new Array();
for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
{
    document.write(cars[i] + "<br>");
    if(cars[i]=="Saab") {   
      totalSuccessArray.push(cars[i]);

        count++;
    }   


}

alert(count);
 document.write(count + "<br>");

for (var a=0;a<count;a++)  {
            document.write("totalssuccess"+totalSuccessArray[a] + "<br>");
}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you declaring and initializing the totalSuccessArray inside your for loop?  This will reinitialize your array every time cars[i] == "Saab"

Comment: These are w3schools cars lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `totalSuccessArray` definition outside your for loop and then `push()`ing the elements onto it like this:

```
cars=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Ford","Saab"];
var count=0;
var totalSuccessArray= new Array();
for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
{
    document.write(cars[i] + "<br>");
    if(cars[i]=="Saab") {
        totalSuccessArray.push(cars[i]);
        count++;
    }   
}
```

In your original code, you're recreating the `totalSuccessArray` every time. In addition, the value you're setting the `totalSuccessArray` to is a string, instead of pushing the string into the array.

Answer (score 3):

In your first for loop, you set `totalSuccessArray` to `"Saab"` (the value held in `cars[i]`).

This means that when you come to reference `totalSuccessArray[a]` in your second for loop, its value is a string. A string is an array of characters, so what this second for loop does is output the first two elements of `"Saab"` i.e. the characters `"S"` and `"a"`.

You need to change the line

```
totalSuccessArray = cars[i];
```

to

```
totalSuccessArray.push(cars[i]);
```

So that you add the value "Saab" to the existing `totalSuccessArray` array.

In addition to this, you should also move the declaration of `totalSuccessArray` to the top of your code, outside the for loop.

There are a number of other optimisations you could also make to this code but that's outside the scope of the specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `totalSuccessArray` to a string, and then iterating over the letters in it. The brackets used on a string returns the character at that position. I think what you meant to do was add the new car to the array:

```
cars=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Ford","Saab"];
var count=0;
var totalSuccessArray= new Array();
for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++) {
    document.write(cars[i] + "<br>");
    if(cars[i]=="Saab") {
        totalSuccessArray[count] = cars[i];
        count++;
    }
}
```